# remove style tags from html in MariaDB

Tags: html, mariadb

i've got longtext with html in MariaDB database and would like to remove style tags with its contents. i'm currently trying the following:

```sql
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnStripStyleRXTag;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION fnStripStyleRXTag( Dirty longtext )
RETURNS longtext
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
  DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
    WHILE Locate( '<style', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '</style>', Dirty, Locate( '<style', Dirty )) > 0 DO
      BEGIN
        SET iStart = Locate( '<style', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '</style>', Dirty, Locate('<style', Dirty ));
        SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 8;
        IF iLength > 0 THEN
          BEGIN
            SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
          END;
        END IF;
      END;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN Dirty;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
SELECT fnStripStyleRXTag('<style id="test">nothing more</style>this <html>is <b>a test</b>, <style class="testovic">nothing more</style></html>');
```

which gives me following result:

```sql
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| fnStripStyleRXTag('<style id="test">nothing more</style>this <html>is <b>a test</b>, <style class="testovic">nothing more</style></html><style>hat</style>') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| this <html>is <b>a test</b>, </html>                                                                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

so essentially it does the job but with some room for errors. so i am wondering if there is a smarter way of doing this. i was thinking of using a wildcard, `Locate( '<style%', Dirty )`, but this doesnt work.

Really appreciate any clues and help. Thank you!

**Update:**

```sql
SELECT VERSION();
+---------------------+
| VERSION()           |
+---------------------+
| 10.11.5-MariaDB-log |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: 10.11.5-MariaDB-log

Comment: Please understand MariaDB and MySQL are different products, and they are not fully compatible. I've edited your text and tags to make it more clear that you're using MariaDB.

Comment: okay, thank you!

Comment: I am not sure that this is any _"better"_, but you can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/) - ``SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(@string, '<style.*?</style>', '');``

Comment: An outside database solution like [Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will probably be more comprehensive.

Comment: @user1191247: REGEXP_REPLACE worked great for me. Do you want to post it as an answer and then i'll accept it. Otherwise I'm also happy to answer myself giving credits of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this is any *"better"*, but you can use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/) to achieve the same result:

```sql
SET @string = '<style id="test">nothing more</style>this <html>is <b>a test</b>, <style class="testovic">nothing more</style></html>';
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(@string, '<style.*?</style>', '');
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE(@string, '<style.*?</style>', '') |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| this <html>is <b>a test</b>, </html>             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```